# Foreign key constraint applied on the same table Spring Boot JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Getting error while saving reports after saving a project object.
It seems like the project table is referencing its own id attribiute for foreign key
But instead it should refer proejct_id in Reports table .

```
2023-04-01 15:31:58.246  WARN 59052 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 547, SQLState: 23000
2023-04-01 15:31:58.247 ERROR 59052 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FKrqfhc8qp99ymovwd852w5mx44". The conflict occurred in database "targetally", table "dbo.projectv2", column 'id'.
2023-04-01 15:31:58.838 ERROR 59052 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FKrqfhc8qp99ymovwd852w5mx44". The conflict occurred in database "targetally", table "dbo.projectv2", column 'id'.
```

I have a Project class .
Project contains a list of report (OneToMany) and list of Access objects for multiple user and user groups to access.

```
@Table(name = "projectv2")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ProjectV2 implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  private String id;

  private String name;

  @Column(name="categories")
  @ElementCollection(targetClass=String.class)
  private List<String> categories;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private ThemeEnum theme;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private ProjectScopeEnum projectScope;

  @CreatedDate
  private LocalDateTime creationDate;

  @LastModifiedDate
  private LocalDateTime lastUpdatedAt;

  @JsonManagedReference(value = "reports")
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private List<ReportV2> reports= new ArrayList<>();

  @JsonManagedReference(value = "userAccess")
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "projectAccess", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private List<EntityAccessV2> userAccess;
}


Following is the reports table
the reports table contains a back reference to Project table, referencing project_id to id in project table.
It also contains list of Access object for multiple users and group of users to access 

@Entity
@Table(name = "reports")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ReportV2 implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  private String id;

  @JsonProperty("projectId")
  private String project_id;

  private String name;

  @ElementCollection(targetClass = String.class)
  private List<String> categories;

  @Convert(converter = LayoutConverterJson.class)
  private Layout layout;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private StateEnum state = StateEnum.DRAFT;

  private String reportSnapshotUrl;

  //private List<SurveyMetadata> surveyMetadataList;

  @CreatedDate
  private LocalDateTime createdAt;

  @LastModifiedDate
  private LocalDateTime updatedAt;

  @JsonBackReference(value = "project")
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "project_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private ProjectV2 project;

  @JsonManagedReference(value = "userAccess")
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "reportAccess", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<EntityAccessV2> userAccess;
}


**The access to any project and report can be separately provided**

@Entity
@Table(name = "entity_access")
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class EntityAccessV2 {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private EntityType entityType;

  private String entityId;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private UserRoleEnum userRole;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private AccessTypeEnum accessType;

  private String value;

  private String username;

  private String email;

  @JsonBackReference(value = "projectAccess")
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @Where(clause = "entityType = 'PROJECT'")
  @JoinColumn(name = "entityId", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false,updatable = false )
  private ProjectV2 projectAccess;

  @JsonBackReference(value = "reportAccess")
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @Where(clause = "entityType = 'REPORT'")
  @JoinColumn(name = "entityId", referencedColumnName = "id",insertable = false,updatable = false)
  private ReportV2 reportAccess;
}


**When I try to add a report the error received is** 

**com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FKrqfhc8qp99ymovwd852w5mx44". The conflict occurred in database "targetally", table "dbo.projectv2", column 'id'.**



**Following is The create statement from Azure Sql is** 


SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[projectv2](
    [id] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [creation_date] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [last_updated_at] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [name] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [project_scope] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [theme] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [categories] [varchar](255) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[projectv2] ADD PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[projectv2]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK268hsfk4bsht8jfpbfw0hnpd3] FOREIGN KEY([id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[projectv2] ([id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[projectv2] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK268hsfk4bsht8jfpbfw0hnpd3]
GO


----------

Following is the save report request 
[![add report request][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7nDG.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[reports]  WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_reports_projectv2] FOREIGN KEY([project_id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[projectv2] ([id])
```

Comment: Works fine when I use the alter table command . Thanks